# Updating first 7 characters of string with another 3 characters using SQL, throws "Error 19 - UNIQUE constraint failed: MGOFile.File."

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a rather simple DB with a column called File, and I need to remove the first 7 characters of each row, and replace with a new string. I thought I had the code sorted, but I am getting error "SQLite3 Error 19 - UNIQUE constraint failed: MGOFile.File."

My table name is MGOFile, and the column is File. This is a simple select statement on the first few rows, the left column is the raw data, the right is what I need the resultant rows to look like...
[image: A Screenshot of my data]

I query my table using this:

```
    '''sql
    SELECT 
      File, 
      'T:\'|| substr(File, 8,2000) as File 
    FROM 
      MGOFile
    WHERE 
      file like 'M:\_TV%';
    '''
```

I then tried updating using this:

```
    UPDATE MGOFile
    SET File = 'T:\' || substr(File, 8, 2000)
    WHERE File like 'M:\_TV%';
```

But here is where my error comes in, this fails with an error:
[image: SQLite3 Error 19 - UNIQUE constraint failed]

I am sure I am doing something simple wrong, but I have done plenty of Googling but all responses are over my head, this is the most advanced SQL I have tried to do!

Any ideas on how to can update these strings with some simple SQLite?

Comment: It implies that this is creating a duplicate filename somewhere (the column File has a unique constraint). You can remove the constraint, or find the duplicates: `select 'T:\'|| substr(File, 8,2000) as File, count(*) from MGOFile group by 'T:\'|| substr(File, 8,2000) having count(*) >1;`

Comment: Thanks @JohnHC, is there a simple bit of SQL that can show the duplicates? I can copy into excel and find them that way, but I am sure that is not standard practice..

Comment: Try `SELECT File from MGOFile WHERE count() > 1 GROUP BY File;`

Comment: @MikeT I get a "misuse of aggregate count()" error

Comment: oops sorry `SELECT File from MGOFile GROUP BY File HAVING count() > 1;` However, if the duplicate is due to the trunctation because of substr(File,8,2000) then the above won't detect it. You could then try `SELECT File from MGOFile GROUP BY substr(File,8,2000) HAVING count() > 1;`

Comment: @MikeT thanks so much for that help, here is the funny thing, that code returns no results. Could this error mean anything else other than a non-unique string will be returned?

Comment: @Benno did you try second with substr ?

Comment: yes i did @MikeT, no results :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As checking for duplicates doesn't appear to detect the issues. Perhaps getting values at the time of the issue may assist. Do you have Triggers by any-chance? These will sometimes propagate an error which will be reported as being with the table that triggered the trigger.

As such perhaps consider adding a table to log such data along with a BEFORE UPDATE TRIGGER to actually log the information at run time. To stop the data being rolled back and thus undoing the logged information OR FAIL needs to be used.

**Important as the updates will not be rolled back updates will have been applied. It is suggested that the above is used on a test database.**

```
-- The code
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS lastupdated;
-- Create the logging table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lastupdated (counter, lastfile_before, lastfile_after, id_of_the_row);
-- Initialise it so it's plain to see if nothing has been done
INSERT INTO lastupdated VALUES(0,'nothing','nothing',0);


-- Add the Trigger to record the debugging information BEFORE the update
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS monitorupdateprogress 
    BEFORE UPDATE ON MGOFile
    BEGIN
        UPDATE lastupdated SET counter = counter +1, lastfile_before = old.File, lastfile_after = new.File, id_of_the_row = old.rowid;
    END
;
UPDATE OR FAIL MGOFile -- OR FAIL will halt but NOT ROLLBACK 
    SET File = 'T:\' || substr(File, 8, 2000)
    WHERE File like 'M:\_TV%';
SELECT * FROM lastupdated; -- will not run if there is a fail but should be run after the fail
```

This would, assuming the fail, record

- the nth update in the **counter** column
- the value in the File column before the change  in the **lastfile_before** column.
- the value that the File column would be updated to in the **lastfile_after* columns.
- the last rowid (failing) of the row in the MGOFile table (this does assume that the MGOFile table is not a table defined using `WITHOUT ROWID`).

  - If the table was defined with the WITHOUT ROWID then you could change `, id_of_the_row = 0;`. The value will then be meaningless.

## Testing/Results the version of the above that was used to test the above is :-

```
-- Solely for testing the code below
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MGOFile;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MGOFile (File TEXT PRIMARY KEY);

-- Some testing data
INSERT INTO MGOFile VALUES
    ('M:\_TV/9-1-1.so2e09.web.x264-tbs[eztv].mkv'),
    ('M:\_TV/9-1-1.so2e09.web.x265-tbs[eztv].mkv'),
    ('M:\_TV/9-1-1.so2e09.web.x266-tbs[eztv].mkv'),
    ('M:\_TV/9-1-1.so2e09.web.x266-tbs[eztv].mkv.so2e09.web.x266-tbs[eztv].mkv.so2e09.web.x266-tbs[eztv].mkv.so2e09.web.x266-tbs[eztv].mkv.so2e09.web.x266-tbs[eztv].mkv.so2e09.web.x266-tbs[eztv].mkv'),
    ('M:\_TV/9-1-1.so2e09.web.x266-tbs[eztv].mkv.so2e09.web.x266-tbs[eztv].mkv.so2e09.web.x266-tbs[eztv].mkv.so2e09.web.x266-tbs[eztv].mkv.so2e09.web.x266-tbs[eztv].mkv.so2e09.web.x277-tbs[eztv].mkv'),
    ('M:\_TV/9-1-1.so2e09.web.x266-tbs[eztv].mkv.so2e09.web.x266-tbs[eztv].mkv.so2e09.web.x266-tbs[eztv].mkv.so2e09.web.x266-tbs[eztv].mkv.so2e09.web.x266-tbs[eztv].mkv.so2e09.web.x278-tbs[eztv].mkv'),
    ('M:\_TV/9-1-1.so2e09.web.x266-tbs[eztv].mkv.so2e09.web.x266-tbs[eztv].mkv.so2e09.web.x266-tbs[eztv].mkv.so2e09.web.x266-tbs[eztv].mkv.so2e09.web.x266-tbs[eztv].mkv.so2e09.web.x279-tbs[eztv].mkv'),
    ('M:\_TV/9-1-1.so2e09.web.x266-tbs[eztv].mkv.so2e09.web.x266-tbs[eztv].mkv.so2e09.web.x266-tbs[eztv].mkv.so2e09.web.x266-tbs[eztv].mkv.so2e09.web.x266-tbs[eztv].mkv.so2e09.web.x280-tbs[eztv].mkv')
;

SELECT substr(File,170,8) FROM MGOFile GROUP BY Substr(File,8,170) HAVING count() > 1;

-- The code
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS lastupdated;
-- Create the logging table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lastupdated (counter, lastfile_before, lastfile_after, id_of_the_row);
-- Initialise it so it's plain to see if nothing has been done
INSERT INTO lastupdated VALUES(0,'nothing','nothing',0);
-- Add the Trigger to record the debugging information BEFORE the update
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS monitorupdateprogress 
    BEFORE UPDATE ON MGOFile
    BEGIN
        UPDATE lastupdated SET counter = counter +1, lastfile_before = old.File, lastfile_after = new.File, id_of_the_row = old.rowid;
    END
;
SELECT * FROM MGOFile;
UPDATE OR FAIL MGOFile -- OR FAIL will halt but NOT ROLLBACK 
    SET File = 'T:\' || substr(File, 8, 170) -- <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< truncate reduced to force UNIQUE constraint
    WHERE File like 'M:\_TV%';
SELECT * FROM lastupdated; -- will not run if there is a fail
```

When the above is run then the message is :-

> ```
> UPDATE OR FAIL MGOFile -- OR FAIL will halt but NOT ROLLBACK 
>     SET File = 'T:\' || substr(File, 8, 170) -- <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< truncate reduced to force UNIQUE constraint
>     WHERE File like 'M:\_TV%'
> > UNIQUE constraint failed: MGOFile.File
> > Time: 0.094s
> ```

Running `SELECT * FROM lastupdated;` returns :-

- counter

  - **6**
- lastfile_before   =

  - **M:_TV/9-1-1.so2e09.web.x266-tbs[eztv].mkv.so2e09.web.x266-tbs[eztv].mkv.so2e09.web.x266-tbs[eztv].mkv.so2e09.web.x266-tbs[eztv].mkv.so2e09.web.x266-tbs[eztv].mkv.so2e09.web.x278-tbs[eztv].mkv**
- lastfile_after

  - **T:\9-1-1.so2e09.web.x266-tbs[eztv].mkv.so2e09.web.x266-tbs[eztv].mkv.so2e09.web.x266-tbs[eztv].mkv.so2e09.web.x266-tbs[eztv].mkv.so2e09.web.x266-tbs[eztv].mkv.so2e09.web.x27**
- id_of_the_row

  - **6**

In the above contrived example the issue can easily be determined (albeit that the duplicate search also found the same issue) as the error is on the 6th row and at the row that contains `mkv.so2e09.web.x278-tbs[eztv]` but was truncated by the update to `.mkv.so2e09.web.x27` hence it is a duplicate of the 5th row which has `.mkv.so2e09.web.x277-tbs[eztv]` but was also truncated to `.mkv.so2e09.web.x27`.

P.S. Have you tried using just

```
UPDATE MGOFile
SET File = 'T:\' || substr(File, 8)
WHERE File like 'M:\_TV%';
```

i.e. removing the truncation.

Comment: Thanks @MikeT for the detailed reply. To answer the easy one first, yes I did try your P.S code earlier, the same error appears. I also tried your full proposal, and yet again I was presented with the same error... Stumped... I dont believe this .db file has any triggers, but it seems the software I am using 'SQLite Spy' may not be showing me everything? Basically I am unsure how to progress... https://imgur.com/73wHsR2

Comment: Note sure about Triggers  then use `SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'trigger';`. Issue with SQlite Spy, try an alternative e,g, DB Browser for SQLite, Navicat. When it failed using the above with the trigger and extra table. Did you use `SELECT * FROM lastupdated;`? have you tried using `substr(File,8) ` (i.e.not truncating at 2000)?

Answer (score 1):

The error seems quite clear to me.  You are changing the file name to a name that is already in the table.

You can identify the duplicates by running:

```
SELECT f.*
FROM MGOFile f
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM MGOFile f2
              WHERE f2.File = 'T:\'|| substr(File, 8,2000)
             ) AND
      f.file LIKE 'M:\_TV%';
```

I don't know what you want to do about the duplicate.

Comment: This is where I am confused, that code does not return any results, making me think it isnt a duplicate PK, I am really stuck with this.